# QGIS addOrderBy doesn't seem to work

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to order one my  features based on some of the attributes from ascending to descending. It works for some of my attribute columns but not others. Are there any requirements for addOrderBy to work?

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy('Length ID',True)):
```

The above doesn't seem to work, but

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy('Circuit',True)):
```

the above works. I have tried to change my Length ID as float, int, and string, but nothing has worked.

Comment: The only difference between both expressions is the name of the attribute. And the one that does not work has a space, which is a special character. If you create a new attribute with the same values ​​but without the space in the name, does it work well?